# Memories in French

Tags: vocabulaire

I am making a scrapbook of me and my boyfriend. I wonder what would be the equivalent of *memories* in French?

Angela and Angelo's memories for example.

Comment: A fair question for a language learner, but the use of a good dictionary requires much less than the hour it takes to wait for a good answer on an exchange site. Always check the separate entries for each meaning. For example, according to Collins, the mental "faculty" of memory is *mémoire* but specific "recollections" are *souvenirs*. This helps figure out which one you need.

Answer (score 10):

It would be *souvenirs*. *Mémoires* is very different, and would refer to a book about memories of a person, close to a biography, maybe more like a *diary*. There are also more technical usages of *mémoires*. In any case, the word you want in your situation is *souvenirs*.

Answer (score -6):

Memories in French is *Les mémoires* which directly translates in to a specific recollection. If you want to find out French words, always check http://www.wordreference.com/fren/.

> les mémoires d'Angela et Angelo.

Comment: This translation would look very weird to a French speaker.

Comment: This answer was in my 'notification box' for approval of someone's editing, most only spelling. I added the link to the online dictionary, which I presumed to be the intention of the original contributor. I don't know anything about the appropriateness of the translation.

Comment: @Catomic I was in a similar position using the review queue for the first time recently. One doesn't know if one should scrap an answer entirely, so one edits it till it's a palatable mush. :p